# Raspberry pi Touch Screen Display unable to connect other modules due to having to use the same pins

Tags: touchscreen, rfid

Good day~ I've been working with a project that involves a raspberry ,a display touch screen, RFID reader and GSM module.

However after setting up the display touch screen for raspberry pi, I noticed that I cannot use the remaining pins or reassign the remaining pins to be connected to the RFID reader and GSM module.

I was wondering if there was a way where I can connect all three modules to the same pins just like how we would connect them for i2c. can I connect the other remaining pins in parallel as well? or is there an alternative where I would be able to use these three modules with the raspberry pi as the main board.

All in all, I'm wondering if it is possible to connect all these 3 modules at once to the raspberry pi and have them working ( maybe parallel connection or reassigning of pins). Does having a touch screen for raspberry pi disables it from having other modules?

EDIT- adding details to what device and what pins the devices use
for the touch screen (3.5 inch Touch Screen TFT) pins to be used are:

```
( pin number , functions)
|(1, 17) 3.3V
|(2 , 4)  5V
|(6, 9, 14, 20 ,25) GND
|11 TP_IRQ
|18 LCD_RS
|19 LCD_SI
|21 TP_SO
|22 RST
|23 LCD_SCK
|24 LCD_CS
|26 TP_CS
```

for the RFID reader (RFID-RC522) pins to be used are:

```
( pin number , functions)
|1 3.3V
|6 GND
|22 RST
|21 MISO
|23 SCK
|24 SDA
|19 MOSI
```

for the GSM module (SIM800L)  , pins to be used are:

```
(pin number, functions)
|6 GND
|2 5V
|14 TX
|15 RX
```

Comment: More details are needed to answer your question. Remember that i2c is designed as a **bus**, whereas individual GPIO pins are not; this is **not** to say that one GPIO pin cannot drive more than one input on different boards, but this requires a full understanding of the interfaces.

Comment: Adding to the first comment: Please [edit] your question and add details about all the hardware you want to connect. How are they supposed to be connected? If possible: What communication protocols do the modules use.

Comment: thank you for the responses, I have added the pins that each devices would use and what functions those pins serve as.